# Absolute rational inequality $\left|\frac{x^2 + 3x + 10}{x + 2}\right| < 7 - x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

First time here. I can't figure out this question only using algebra. I can only solve it using graph.

> Find the set of values for which $$\left|\frac{x^2 + 3x + 10}{x + 2}\right| < 7 - x$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Can you start by solving when the two sides of the inequality are equal?

Comment: I can sketch the graph and then using the graph to solve this inequality. And yes, I can solve it when the inequality are equal. But I don't know without sketching the graph, how to solve this inequality by only algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of things to notice:

1. You have to have $x\leq 7$ since an absolute value has to be at least zero.
2. If you complete the square in that numerator, you can see that the numerator is always positive, so it doesn't have to be inside the absolute value.